# Fast random row in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to generate a random row from my MySql database and i have found example here:
http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/

And i want to use solution 3 which looks like this:

```
$offset_result = mysql_query( " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `users` ");
$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object( $offset_result ); 
$offset = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT $offset, 1 " );
```

My code looks like this now:

```
$offset_result = mysql_query( " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `users` ");
$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object( $offset_result ); 
$offset = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE profile_image='2' LIMIT $offset, 1 " );
$random_date = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $random_date['user_name']; //display username of random user
```

But when i refresh the page: approximatly 7 of 10 times nonthing shows up. No username at all and also im trying to print out the id of the user but it's also empty. 
It seems that it's not getting anything at all from the database when refreshing and sometimes it get's data from the database. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: You're using RAND in your example?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste `LIMIT 0, 1` will fetch the first object; also, a probability of 70% seems pretty high for that scenario.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't calculate the random offset with PHP, based on the number of rows in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, the problem is that you're working with two *different* queries; the first query is:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `users`
```

Whereas the second one includes a condition:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE profile_image='2' LIMIT $offset, 1
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Both queries should operate over the same result set.

Comment: Yeah now i get the names. But how do i add so i can display only users who have profile image and who's gender is male 

Like WHERE profile_image='2' AND gender='male'
How do i add that?

Comment: @Mensur Whatever conditions you choose to use, just make sure to apply them on *both* queries.

Answer (score 1):

Its because in your first query you dont have a where, but in the second query you do.

if you have 50 rows and only 15 with `profile_image = 2` That will be the reason why most appear as nothing.

Your query becomes `LIMIT 30,1` when there are only 15 results for example

Make sure the same where is used in both queries.

Also avoid using mysql_* functions in new code

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem was this, BIG thanks to: @Jack

This query will find random row in a mysql table very fast.

```
$gender_search =  $logged_in_user['gender_search'];

$offset_result = mysql_query( " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `users` WHERE profile_image='2' AND gender='$gender_search'");
$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object( $offset_result ); 
$offset = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE profile_image='2' AND gender='$gender_search' LIMIT $offset, 1 " );
$random_date = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

I have now converted this string to PDO if someone needs it.

```
$statement = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `users` WHERE profile_image=? AND gender=?");
$statement->execute(array('2',$logged_in_user['gender_search']));
$offset_row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$offset = $offset_row->offset;

$statement2 = $dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE profile_image=? AND gender=? LIMIT ?, 1");
$statement2->execute(array('2', $logged_in_user['gender_search'], $offset));
$random_date = $statement2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```