# How can to select a random row from a MySQL database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database table `questions` on a online web server with 2000+ rows and I need to get 6 randomly selected rows. They must be different so that one question is not two times in the list array of 6 questions.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `select * from table order by rand() limit 6` ?

Comment: use `your query with RAND() LIMIT 10;`

Comment: But there is possibility some question to match another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast random row in MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330510/fast-random-row-in-mysql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a relatively small amount of data, so the simplest method is:

```
select q.*
from questions q
order by rand()
limit 6;
```

In this query, the `order by` takes the longest amount of time.  Ordering 2,000 rows might be noticeable.  A simple fix is to reduce the number of rows being ordered.  One method is:

```
select q.*
from questions q cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from questions) m
where rand() < 100 / m.cnt
order by rand()
limit 6;
```

The `where` selects about 100 rows randomly and then orders those to select 6.  You are pretty much guaranteed that the `where` will always choose at least 6 rows.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html) operator in MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6;
```

So `DISTINCT` will take care and remove duplicates